# RPA supplier invoices

Tags: rpa

I was wondering if anyone has automated the processing of supplier invoices with an RPA system

My question is as invoices come in in different formats depending on the supplier do you need one robot per supplier?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually no, one robot can have different procedures for different invoice formats and choose them during the processing. Nevertheless it may be pretty hard to maintain, let's say, more than 3 formats.

Answer (score 1):

Divide the process of invoice capturing into two parts.
Gather data & insert data.

While insert data into SAP or another application is same for each invoicing company.

Gathering of the data is more challenging topic.

- You can define each customer as a template. You will use keywords on the invoice to distinguish between invoices and then parse data which are necessary to capture.
- Use third party software to gathering of the data. Usually AI taking care of gathering the data. You just need to insert couple of invoice as an example for the AI. Do not want to make any propagation, but there are companies like: https://rossum.ai/, https://typless.com/ etc..

Answer (score 1):

Each supplier has its own format/pattern of invoice and your invoice parser should be trained with each format/pattern. Sometime you may have to train/tune the AI model within the parser to achieve more than 90% accuracy.
So, from RPA standpoint, there could be one bot that will trigger the AI invoice parser and invoice parser needs to be trained with each pattern of invoices.